# Do object references take up extra memory?

Tags: javascript, object, memory, memory-management

Lets say you have the following complex object:

```
var object1 = .... // (something complexed)
```

This takes up `x` amount of memory in your JS application. Now lets say you have some other objects that reference `object1`:

```
var otherObject = { something: true, value: 'yes', object: object1 };

var anotherObject = { color: '#FFF', object: object1 };
```

Have I tripled the amount of memory that `object1` originally took up? Or do the references to `object1` not add to the overhead of the memory used?

I'm not sure how to test this myself in order to determine the answer. (Bonus points if you can tell me how to point me to a tool that helps benchmark this).

Comment: Seems to be a good question

Comment: Well, you'd need some memory to indicate that the reference does exist. Otherwise, how'd you know if it's there or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Objects are always passed by reference in JavaScript (see this [popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/239599)). Pointer to an object takes some amount of memory (depends on implementation), of course, but much less than the actual object.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language?rq=1).  Numbers, strings, etc. are always called by value, but objects are [called by sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing); that is they are called by value, but the value is a reference to the object.

In other words, if you modify the pointer's properties, you are modifying the same pool of memory as the object.  But if you reassign the pointer, it does not affect the original object.

What this means is that, in your example, you have *not* tripled the amount of memory that `object1` took up, **but** the extra pointers to `object1` will take up *some* memory space. Exactly how much space? That depends on the precise implementation of the Javascript engine, but it will always be much less than the size of the object.

As far as benchmarking goes, look at Mozilla's documentation for their JS engine, [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey).  There are lots of good utilities there....